# PHP: Parse Error: unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, syntax-error

My code gives me the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')' line 208

I keep getting this but it looks correct? Line 208 which is the second down.

```
array( "name" => "Colour Scheme",
 "desc" => "Select the colour scheme for the theme",
 "id" => $shortname."_color_scheme",
 "type" => "select",
 "options" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
 "std" => "blue"),
```

please advise!

Thanks

Comment: There's no error here.  Often errors can come up on a line, when the problem is actually right before it (for example missing `;` at line end).  Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 4):

`T_DOUBLE_ARROW` is the token for `=>`, so you have one which appears somewhere the parser doesn't expect it.

Besides that trailing `,`, there is no error with the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is some code just before and after.

Answer (score 0):

> Besides that trailing ,, there is no error with the code you posted. -- alex
>
> Often errors can come up on a line, when the problem is actually right before it (for example missing ; at line end) -- Jonah

My bet is that Jonah is correct and that the error in the line above this array.  From the context of the trailing `,` I bet this is a mutli-dimensional array.

If you include the code around your array I bet the problem is the line above.

Good luck.

Comment: array( "name" => "General",
 "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),
 
array( "name" => "Colour Scheme",
 "desc" => "Select the colour scheme for the theme",
 "id" => $shortname."_color_scheme",
 "type" => "select",
 "options" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
 "std" => "blue"),

array( "name" => "Logo URL",
 "desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
 "id" => $shortname."_logo",
 "type" => "text",
 "std" => ""),