# PHP error unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code in Wordress to create my nav but for some reason, I keep getting the same error.

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( 'menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu'); ?>  
</nav>
```

**error**

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
```

Many thanks,
P

Comment: You're using array syntax without an array: `wp_nav_menu( array('menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu'));` or `wp_nav_menu( ['menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu']);` if you're using a modern version of PHP that supports short array syntax

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Parse Error: unexpected T\_DOUBLE\_ARROW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847094/php-parse-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow)

Answer (score 4):

This [function expects array](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), so it should be:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu')); ?>  
</nav>
```

Comment: @Rizier123: Because I have a google http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu. I've edited my answer, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I will just add here the reference if OP wants to read more about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: This `solution` is correct but the `diagnosis` and the `explanation` aren't. Just because that function expects an array does not mean that if you don't send in an array that will result in a parse error. That parse error is caused by the fact that the array notation was used incorrectly. If you send in any normal variable to that function instead of an array it will not result in  a parse error. That's the explanation :)

Comment: They are already trying to send it an array, just that it does not have  proper syntax. Either it needs to have `array` around it or it simply needs those `()` converted to `[]` if they have 5.4+, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu_id' => 'navigation', 'menu_class' => 'slimmenu'));
```

Comment: And what additional information does your answer have, which [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28738382/3933332) doesn't have?